# how to get application insights to recognise .net sessions? Jmeter traffic not showing in AI

Tags: jmeter, application-insights

application insights has various graphs and queries to show number of users/sessions authenticated and not.

However, this is not working for sessions created with jmeter. Jmeter is correctly tracking the servers cookies, including the .net session cookie.

e.g. if I have a jmeter test with 100 users (threads), and 50 iterations/loop counts, and "use same user on each iteration" isabled, I would expect to see 5000 sessions, as its generating 5000 different .net session IDs.

However, for the test period, in AI, I only see max 1 session, which is probably me hitting the site with a browser.

with AI, you generally embed a js snipped in your page to allow AI to do better tracking, but how do we get this to work via jmeter (which cant execute js)?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if your session tracking relies on JavaScript code execution you won't be able to get it out of the box (unless you manually add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to post the revelant event to the AI backend)

What you can get out of the box would be monitoring i.e. [HTTP Request Rate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/app-insights-metrics#http-request-rate-performancecountersrequestspersecond)

Also there are some custom charts like [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) which don't require any extra configuration, you can install them using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)